# ORA-06502 error when insert from Java but work fine in TOAD

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ora-06502

I am inserting a row in my table from Java and I got the following error below.
But the same sql query executed in TOAD insert my data without problem.

The insert :

```
INSERT INTO TRAVAUX_FICHE(date1, date2, description, cie , work_id) 
VALUES(TO_DATE('2014-08-15','yyyy-MM-dd'), TO_DATE('2014-08-15','yyyy-MM-dd'), 'test', 'test','test');
```

The error

```
ORA-20999: TAPI--6502:ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
TAPI--6502:ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "PILOTAGE.CG$ERRORS", line 87
ORA-06512: at "PERMIS.CG$TRAVAUX_FICHE", line 557
ORA-06512: at "PERMIS.CG$BIR_TRAVAUX_FICHE", line 51
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'PERMIS.CG$BIR_TRAVAUX_FICHE'
```

EDIT for TRIGGER CODE (I didnt write the trigger code, It is generated I think) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cg$BIR_TRAVAUX_FICHE

BEFORE INSERT ON TRAVAUX_FICHE FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
cg$rec cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$row_type;
cg$ind cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$ind_type;
BEGIN
--  Application_logic Pre-Before-Insert-row <<Start>>
--  Application_logic Pre-Before-Insert-row << End >>

--  Load cg$rec/cg$ind values from new

cg$rec.NO_TRAV_FICHE_SQ := :new.NO_TRAV_FICHE_SQ;
cg$ind.NO_TRAV_FICHE_SQ := TRUE;
cg$rec.DATE_DEBUT := :new.DATE_DEBUT;
cg$ind.DATE_DEBUT := TRUE;
cg$rec.DATE_FIN := :new.DATE_FIN;
cg$ind.DATE_FIN := TRUE;
cg$rec.DESCRIPTION := :new.DESCRIPTION;
cg$ind.DESCRIPTION := TRUE;
cg$rec.COMPAGNIE := :new.COMPAGNIE;
cg$ind.COMPAGNIE := TRUE;
cg$rec.NUM_APPEL_OFFRE := :new.NUM_APPEL_OFFRE;
cg$ind.NUM_APPEL_OFFRE := TRUE;
cg$rec.DATE_CREATION := :new.DATE_CREATION;
IF (:new.DATE_CREATION IS NULL) THEN
    cg$ind.DATE_CREATION := FALSE;
ELSE
    cg$ind.DATE_CREATION := TRUE;
END IF;
cg$rec.USAGER_CREATION := :new.USAGER_CREATION;
IF (:new.USAGER_CREATION IS NULL) THEN
    cg$ind.USAGER_CREATION := FALSE;
ELSE
    cg$ind.USAGER_CREATION := TRUE;
END IF;
cg$rec.DATE_MODIFICATION := :new.DATE_MODIFICATION;
IF (:new.DATE_MODIFICATION IS NULL) THEN
    cg$ind.DATE_MODIFICATION := FALSE;
ELSE
    cg$ind.DATE_MODIFICATION := TRUE;
END IF;
cg$rec.USAGER_MODIFICATION := :new.USAGER_MODIFICATION;
IF (:new.USAGER_MODIFICATION IS NULL) THEN
    cg$ind.USAGER_MODIFICATION := FALSE;
ELSE
    cg$ind.USAGER_MODIFICATION := TRUE;
END IF;

if not (cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.called_from_package) then
    cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.validate_arc(cg$rec);
    cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.validate_domain(cg$rec);

    cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.ins(cg$rec, cg$ind, FALSE);
    cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.called_from_package := FALSE;
end if;

cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$table(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).NO_TRAV_FICHE_SQ := cg$rec.NO_TRAV_FICHE_SQ;
cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$tableind(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).NO_TRAV_FICHE_SQ := cg$ind.NO_TRAV_FICHE_SQ;

cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$table(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).DATE_DEBUT := cg$rec.DATE_DEBUT;
cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$tableind(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).DATE_DEBUT := cg$ind.DATE_DEBUT;

cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$table(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).DATE_FIN := cg$rec.DATE_FIN;
cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$tableind(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).DATE_FIN := cg$ind.DATE_FIN;

cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$table(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).DESCRIPTION := cg$rec.DESCRIPTION;
cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$tableind(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).DESCRIPTION := cg$ind.DESCRIPTION;

cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$table(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).COMPAGNIE := cg$rec.COMPAGNIE;
cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$tableind(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).COMPAGNIE := cg$ind.COMPAGNIE;

cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$table(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).NUM_APPEL_OFFRE := cg$rec.NUM_APPEL_OFFRE;
cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$tableind(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).NUM_APPEL_OFFRE := cg$ind.NUM_APPEL_OFFRE;

cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$table(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).DATE_CREATION := cg$rec.DATE_CREATION;
cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$tableind(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).DATE_CREATION := cg$ind.DATE_CREATION;

cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$table(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).USAGER_CREATION := cg$rec.USAGER_CREATION;
cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$tableind(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).USAGER_CREATION := cg$ind.USAGER_CREATION;

cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$table(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).DATE_MODIFICATION := cg$rec.DATE_MODIFICATION;
cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$tableind(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).DATE_MODIFICATION := cg$ind.DATE_MODIFICATION;

cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$table(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).USAGER_MODIFICATION := cg$rec.USAGER_MODIFICATION;
cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.cg$tableind(cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx).USAGER_MODIFICATION := cg$ind.USAGER_MODIFICATION;

cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx := cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.idx + 1;

:new.NO_TRAV_FICHE_SQ := cg$rec.NO_TRAV_FICHE_SQ;
:new.DATE_DEBUT := cg$rec.DATE_DEBUT;
:new.DATE_FIN := cg$rec.DATE_FIN;
:new.DESCRIPTION := cg$rec.DESCRIPTION;
:new.COMPAGNIE := cg$rec.COMPAGNIE;
:new.NUM_APPEL_OFFRE := cg$rec.NUM_APPEL_OFFRE;
:new.DATE_CREATION := cg$rec.DATE_CREATION;
:new.USAGER_CREATION := cg$rec.USAGER_CREATION;
:new.DATE_MODIFICATION := cg$rec.DATE_MODIFICATION;
:new.USAGER_MODIFICATION := cg$rec.USAGER_MODIFICATION;

--  Application_logic Post-Before-Insert-row <<Start>>
--  Application_logic Post-Before-Insert-row << End >>
END;
/
```

Do you have any ideas  ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is in the execution of the trigger.  You should edit the question and show the code for the trigger.

Comment: The error is in the trigger PERMIS.CG$BIR_TRAVAUX_FICHE as shown by the error message. Update your question with the trigger code.

Comment: Error is in `PILOTAGE.CG$ERRORS` line 87..as per stacktrace!

Comment: Yes, this is basic debugging really; line 51 of the trigger seems to be `cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.ins(cg$rec, cg$ind, FALSE);`, so line 557 of that package is presumably in the `ins` procedure; and is calling `cg$ERRORS`, line 87 of which has the actual problem. From that name hard to guess if that means it's already hit an error and isn't handling it well, or if it's supposed to be calling that.

Comment: @AlexPoole
The error at : "PERMIS.CG$BIR_TRAVAUX_FICHE", line 51
is the second line below of the trigger code 
        if not (cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.called_from_package) then
            cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.validate_arc(cg$rec);
            cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.validate_domain(cg$rec);

            cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.ins(cg$rec, cg$ind, FALSE);
            cg$TRAVAUX_FICHE.called_from_package := FALSE;
        end if;

Comment: @Caffé 
I updated the trigger code.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar , the function PILOTAGE.CG$ERRORS is an old function used by another package so I find strange that the problem is in there.

Comment: You need the code for `"PERMIS.CG$TRAVAUX_FICHE", line 557` - the `"PILOTAGE.CG$ERRORS"` could just be error handling... you can look in `ALL_SOURCE` to see what line number Oracle thinks things are. Look in both - it is likely something to do with session defaults if it works in TOAD but not JAVA (e.g. assuming certain date format, character set issues, ...)

Comment: @curvenut - the line number reported is in the PL/SQL block; the first three lines of your trigger statement don't count. Line 1 is the `DECLARE`. (My guess would be something putting a date into a string in an unexpected format due to NLS settings).

Comment: @AlexPoole, but my insert command above is working fine in toad.

You think that in Java it cause problems ?

Comment: @Captain,  what do you mean by "All_SOURCE" ??   THanks

Comment: ALL_SOURCE is an internal Oracle table that contains the source code of the packages, procedures, triggers, etc.